# Marketing Cloud - Do Accounts count toward license limit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, licenses

What seems as an obvious "no" - till today - has turned around a bit:

We have seen this official doc - about Contact Delete - that states (last paragraph) that Accounts count towards total Contacts.

[image]

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313920&type=1&mode=1

On the other hand there is this article which doesn't include Accounts:

[image]

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_definition_and_count_determination.htm&type=5

Verdict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is still No. Account doesn't count under the contacts.

```
To check it, you can go to Reports > Contact Catalogue > Contact Count as Report Name.
```

You can see that column doesn't include any counts related to Account.

[image]

To answer your first part, Salesforce help doc is mentioning about the contact deletion. Sometimes, we might use account Id as subscriber key you can just replace contact_salesforce with Account_Salesforce or any other customer object and check if any subscriber is present. If yes, you can delete it.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hey Naveen,
Thanks for the reply. What do you mean by: you can just replace contact_salesforce with Account_Salesforce. ? 
Where do we replace that?

Comment: Hello @LimeWeb...In your screenshot there is a query contact_salesforce you can replace that with Account_salesforce or any other custom object to check if that is part of contact. Because sometimes people do use Account or other objects as subscriber key (which is not recommended) and send an email. So it takes that as a contact. To check if any account or other object as contact key you can change the SQL query and check. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: got it, thanks!